# How to get Activity Info from an IDialogContext

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I'm using a LuisDialog and all I get the the callback returns is an IDialogContext and the LuisResult.
Is there a way I can get info from the original Activity, like channel, from name, et al?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since the v3.2.0 release you can access the original incoming message from the intent handlers. Check [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/blob/master/CSharp/Samples/AlarmBot/Dialogs/AlarmLuisDialog.cs#L108) to understand how your intent handler should looks like.

```
public async Task MyHandler(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> activity, LuisResult result)
```

Alternatively, you can use context.MakeMessage but I would recommend updating your intent handlers.

Comment: thanks, BTW with `context.MakeMessage` you can't get the text from the original Activity, so I guess upgrading is a must :)

Comment: Correct. If you need the original text, you must go with the newest intent handler signature.

Comment: When I use this in my intent, It shows an exception with intent name in exception message "none". I think it means it could not find the none intent with same signature.

Comment: Do you have to change the syntax of your messagescontroller in order to get it to work? I don't know how to do it. Help!!!

Comment: Have you updated the version of the BotBuilder nuget package? Do you have a none intent both in the code and in Luis?