# Microsoft Bot Framework forwarding to dialog is not working correctly

Tags: c#, botframework

I have 2 Dialogs. In the first one I forward to the second one if the result matches my criteria, the code looks like this:

```
/// <summary>
/// Intent for choosing a category
/// </summary>
/// <param name="context">The current context</param>
/// <param name="result">The Luis result</param>
/// <returns></returns>
[LuisIntent("Choose category")]
public async Task ChooseCategory(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
{

    // Get our category
    var category = TryFindCategory(result);
    var response = "The category you have chosen is not in the system just yet.";

    switch (category)
    {
        case "camera":

            // If our category is a camera, forward to our QuestionDialog
            await context.Forward(new QuestionDialog(), ResumeAfter, new Activity { Text = result.Query }, CancellationToken.None);
            break;
        default:

            // If we have an unknown category, update the response message
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(category)) response = $"Sorry, PiiiCK does not deal with { category.Pluralise() } just yet.";

            // Post our response back to the user
            await context.PostAsync(response);

            // Execute the message recieved delegate
            context.Wait(MessageReceived);
            break;
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Delgate function for resuming after a response have been recieved from LUIS
/// </summary>
/// <param name="context">The current context</param>
/// <param name="result">The Luis result</param>
/// <returns></returns>
private async Task ResumeAfter(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
{
    context.Wait(MessageReceived);
}
```

I have set my question dialog up like this:

```
[Serializable]
public class QuestionDialog : IDialog<object>
{

    // Private properties
    private readonly QuestionGroupService _questionGroupService;
    private IList<QuestionGroup> _questionGroups;

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets a list of QuestionGroups
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>A list of QuestionGroups</returns>
    public async Task<IList<QuestionGroup>> QuestionGroups() => _questionGroups ?? (_questionGroups = await _questionGroupService.ListAllAsync());

    /// <summary>
    /// Default constructor
    /// </summary>
    public QuestionDialog()
    {
        _questionGroupService = new QuestionGroupService(new UnitOfWork<DatabaseContext>());
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Start our response
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">The current context</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public async Task StartAsync(IDialogContext context) => context.Wait(ActivityRecievedAsync);

    /// <summary>
    /// When our message is recieved we execute this delegate
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">The current context</param>
    /// <param name="result">The result object</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private async Task ActivityRecievedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {

        // Get our activity
        var activity = await result as Activity;

        // If it contains test
        await context.PostAsync("This is my first question?");
        context.Wait(GroupOneAnswerAsync);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="context">The current context</param>
    /// <param name="result">The result object</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private async Task GroupOneAnswerAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {

        // Get our activity
        var activity = await result as Activity;

        // If it contains test
        await context.PostAsync("This is my second question?");
        context.Wait(GroupTwoAnswerAsync);
    }

    private async Task GroupTwoAnswerAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {

        // Get our activity
        var activity = await result as Activity;

        // If it contains test
        await context.PostAsync("This is my third question?");
        context.Wait(GroupThreeAnswerAsync);
    }

    private async Task GroupThreeAnswerAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {

        // Get our activity
        var activity = await result as Activity;

        // If it contains test
        await context.PostAsync("This is my third question?");
        context.Wait(GetResultsAsync);
    }

    private async Task GetResultsAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {

        // Get our activity
        var activity = await result as Activity;

        // If it contains test
        await context.PostAsync("These are my results");
        context.Wait(ActivityRecievedAsync);
    }
}
```

When I test this, when the first Dialog forwards to the second one, it invokes the **StartAsync** method, but **ActivityRecievedAsync** is never invoked.
Does anyone know why?

Comment: I don't have a laptop now handy to debug, but can you try the following: Change the signature of your ChooseCategory intent method, to have a 3 parameters, instead of 2, being the second one: IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> activity. Then try sending that activity instead of the one you are creating to the dialog

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work either :(

Comment: I meant the await of the activity, but you figured out that

Comment: Yeah, I tried it and I get the same issue :( I wish there was some documentation on context.Forward...

Comment: oh wait, I know what's going! change the signature of ActivityRecievedAsync to be IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> instead of IAwaitable<object> it doesn't matter the dialog is an IDialog<object> that "object" is for the outcome othe dialog (context.Done) not for the input

Comment: Yeah did that ages ago too :D still the same issue :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/128174/discussion-between-ezequiel-jadib-and-r3plica).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the discussion you have in the chat, make sure you are running the latest version of the BotBuilder as we might be hitting a known issue in a previous version.

Also (not related to the issue, but as a good practice) you might want to change the signature of

```
private async Task ActivityRecievedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
```

to

```
private async Task ActivityRecievedAsync(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> result)
```

Having your dialog being `IDialog<object>` it doesn't dictate that the very first input of the dialog has to be a object. It just says that the dialog will return an `object` when you perform a `context.Done`.

Also, you can use the incoming message that went to LUIS to do the forward instead of manually creating the activity (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39374494/how-to-get-activity-info-from-an-idialogcontext/39376257#39376257)). Just change the signature of the intent method to

```
public async Task ChooseCategory(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> activity, LuisResult result)
```

await the activity parameter and use that in the context.Forward

Some interesting resources:

- A good sample around [Multi-dialogs](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/blob/master/CSharp/core-MultiDialogs)
- [Calling Forms from Dialogs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37522294/calling-forms-from-dialogs/37525465#37525465)

Comment: Yeah, this worked well. The errors were due to being 1 minor version out, but I agree with your best practice, so I have made sure they are all like that. For the LUIS signature, it was the Entity I needed, not the original Activity which is why I didn't use it in my initial post, but it is something to be aware of because I might need it in the future! :D