# IMessageActivity as parameter

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

According to this thread, 
[How to get Activity Info from an IDialogContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39374494/how-to-get-activity-info-from-an-idialogcontext) i changed all my method-intents in code:

I am calling my LuisDialog from MessagesController this way :

```
 await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new RootLuisDialog());
```

and then in method :

```
    [LuisIntent("test-intent")]
            public async Task help(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> activity  LuisResult result)
            {

 await Conversation.SendAsync(activity  , () => SimpleFacebookAuthDialog.dialog);

    }
```

So when i run this it throws an exception :

> {";None"}

and stacktrace :

> at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.LuisDialog.d__0.MoveNext()\r\n
>   at
>   System.Linq.Enumerable.ToDictionary[TSource,TKey,TElement](IEnumerable`1
>   source, Func`2 keySelector, Func`2 elementSelector,
>   IEqualityComparer`1 comparer)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.LuisDialog`1.GetHandlersByIntent()\r\n
>
>   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.LuisDialog`1.d__6.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.ThunkResume`1.<Rest>d__4.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(
>   Task task)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait`2.-PollAsync>d__19.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Frame`1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFrameLoop<C>-PollAsync>d__7.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Fiber`1.-PollAsync>d__13.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown 
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n
>   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait`2.Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.IAwaiter<T>.GetResult()\r\n
>   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Chain.LoopDialog`1.d__3.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.ThunkResume`1.<Rest>d__4.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Wait`2.-PollAsync>
>   d__19.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location
>   where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Frame`1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Internals-Fibers-IFrameLoop<C>-PollAsync>d__7.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.Fiber`1.-PollAsync>d__13.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServic
>   es.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n 
>   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.d__21`1.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ReactiveDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__5`1.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.LocalizedDialogTask.d__2
>   `1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ScoringDialogTask`1.d__6`1.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PersistentDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__6`1.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PersistentDialogTask.d__6`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack
>   trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Conversation.d__4.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Conversation.d__2.MoveNext()\r\n---
>   End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown
>   ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)\r\n   at System
>   .Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()\r\n   at
>   MessengerBot.MessagesController.d__1.MoveNext() in
>   C:\app\Controllers\MessagesController.cs:line 52"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to "wait" for the `IAwaitable<IMessageActivity>` parameter:

```
[LuisIntent("test-intent")]
public async Task help(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<IMessageActivity> argument, LuisResult result)
{
    var activity = await argument;
    await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => SimpleFacebookAuthDialog.dialog);
}
```

Comment: This does not work. It throws same exception. 
I changed all the intents and add var `activity = await argument;` into it.

Comment: What function is that? My bot doesn't use dialogs but this code is [from the documentation](https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/csharp/builder/sdkreference/dialogs.html#simpleEcho), adapted to the code you posted.

Comment: Function defined into the LuisDialog. I cannot get activity into it. I want to call another dialog based on that intent.... Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to upgrade your old bot to the newest version. Doing that will give you `context.Activity`. Make your own choice.

Comment: I am the author of this post actually :))))